# Matlab parallel computing - Simultaneous play and record

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I want to play a pure tone and record from the default microphone simultaneously using Matlab.

```
%% Main code   
frequency = 500;
time = 5;

tic
parfor ii = 1:2
    if ii==1
        recording = test_record(time);
    elseif ii==2
        test_play(frequency,time);
    end
end
toc

size(recording)
```

This all works fine except that *recording* variable is not available after the parfor loop ends and I need it for further analysis. I'd appreciate suggestions of how to make the recorded sample available after the parforloop or even better - I'll be happy to learn if a better design is preferable.

Thanks!

---

Here are the two additional functions used for running the above code :

```
%% Play the given frequency
function test_play(frequency,recording_time)
fs = 8000; % Samples per second
t = 0:(1/fs):recording_time;
y =  sin(2*pi*frequency*t);
sound(y, fs);
end

%% Record from the microphone for given number of seconds
function recording = test_record(recording_time)
recObj = audiorecorder;
recordblocking(recObj, recording_time);
recording = getaudiodata(recObj);
end
```

Note - A [related question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923137/playing-an-array-as-sound-and-recording-its-output-in-parallel) answer redirect to some program (*Sox*) that seem to do what I search for, however I want to write the Matlab code myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, recording is a local variable which remains on the worker. This code creates a sliced cell array which should fix it:

```
%% Main code   
frequency = 500;
time = 5;
recording=cell(2,1)
parfor ii = 1:2
    if ii==1
        recording{ii} = test_record(time);
    elseif ii==2
        test_play(frequency,time);
    end
end
```

Obviously, your data is recording{1}